# Counting of Array subscripting operator

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I would like to write counter of occurences of array subscripting operators in .c file. Problem is the input file can be very complicated, e.g.:

```
string[0] = 'R';
a[1] = 0;
a[ 1] = 0;
a[1 ] = 0;
a[ 1 ] = 0;
a[1+i] = 0;
a[ 1+i] = 0;
a[1+i ] = 0;
a[ 1+i ] = 0;
a[ 1 + i ] = 0;

a[a[0] + a[a[0]+1] + i] = 0;
a[a[0] + a[a[0]+1] + i] = (int)a[a[a[a[a[(int)i]]]] + i];

a = "retezec"[0];
a = (p1+p2)[0];

multiarray[1][2] [3]    [4]
[5] = 0;

// int *getArray(int a){
//   return a;
// }

getArray(a)[0] = getArray(a)[1]
getArray(a)[i+1] = getArray(a)[i+1]
getArray(
a
)
[i+1] = getArray(
a
)    [i+1]
```

...where is 36 array subscripting operators.
Have you any idea how to write this in python

EDIT:  operators in DECLARATION can't be counted, e.g.:

```
int field[1][a]; //0 operators !!
field[2][4];     //2 operators
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python...

however your problem seems simple. Assuming the c code is error free you can merely count the '[' occurrences.

so in c++ it might look like

```
for (int n=0; n < stringOfText.length(); ++n)
    if (stringOfText[n] == '[')
        arraySubscriptOperatorCounter++;
```

**Adjusted**
so it will meet your requirements (c++, and doesn't include getting the text from the file *will add on request*)

```
#include <iostream>

inline size_t findNext (const std::string& s, char c, size_t pos =0, bool reverse =false) {
    if (reverse)
        return s.substr(0,pos).rfind(c);
    else if (!reverse)
        return s.substr(pos).find(c);
}

int main () {
    std::string s;
    int opCount(0);
    for (int n(0); n < s.length(); ++n) {
        if (s[n] == '[') {
            size_t prev_sem = findNext(s, ';', (size_t)n, true);
            size_t prev_equ = findNext(s, '=', (size_t)n, true);
            size_t next_sem = findNext(s, ';', (size_t)n);
            size_t next_equ = findNext(s, '=', (size_t)n);

            if (prev_sem == std::string::npos)
                prev_sem = 0;
            if (prev_equ == std::string::npos)
                prev_equ = 0;


            if (prev_equ > prev_sem) {
                opCount++;
            }
            else if (next_equ < next_sem && next_equ != std::string::npos) {
                opCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << opCount;
}
```

Comment: check the edited question, in this case, your solution won't work

Comment: Must it be python?(I cannot comment on the question)

Comment: i work with python , but if you help me in another language, it would be helpful.

Comment: @DRINK Tested it with a few inputs. It assumes error-free code

Comment: @DRINK also it counts if a declaration and assignment are made in one statment

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> open('test.c').read().count('[')
36
```

Or safer:

```
>>> with open('test.c') as f: f.read().count('[')
36
```

That of course can't handle all cases (it would for example count `[` if it's in a string). You might want to use a proper parser.

Comment: check the edited question, in this case, your solution won't work

Comment: @DRINK Well in that case, my "You might want to use a proper parser." part applies.